# PHP title and meta tag dynamics

Tags: php

I'm designing a dynamic layout and every pages are included on index.php.
In that page there isn't any code. Just the content.
This is my index

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Text | <?php echo'$text;'?></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="it" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="template/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="config/jsmenu.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="config/menu.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="config/expand.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="config/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="config/scriptbreaker-multiple-accordion-1.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".topnav").accordion({
            accordion:false,
            speed: 500,
            closedSign: '[+]',
            openedSign: '[-]'
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="banner"><?php include('template/banner.php') ?></div>
            <!--<div id="nav_main"><?php include('template/nav_main.php') ?></div> -->
            <div id="navigation_left"><?php include("template/link_left.php") ?></div>      
            <div id="navigation_right" align="left"><?php include("template/link_right.php") ?></div>                               
            <div id="content"><?php include("$page.php") ?></div>
            <div id="footer"><?php include('template/footer.php') ?></div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

$page is generated by this or other pieces contained in link_left.php or link_right.php

```
    <?php
        isset($_GET["page"]) ? $page=$_GET["page"] : $page="home";
        $links=array(
            "fmp_trama" => "Full Metal Panic!",
            "fumoffu_trama" => "Full Metal Panic? Fumoffu",
            "fmptsr" => "Full Metal Panic! TSR",
            "riassunti" => "Riassunti Episodi",
            "manga" => "Manga",
            "listamanga" => "Lista Manga",
            "lnrecensione" => "Romanzo",
            "romanzi" => "Lista Romanzi",
            "sigma" => "Sigma",
            "overload" => "Overload",
            "comicmission" => "Comic Mission",
            "another" => "Another",
            "sdnefd" => "SDNED",
            "zero" => "Zero",
            "riassunti_manga" => "Riassunti Manga",
            "riassuntiromanzi" => "Riassunti Romanzi"
        );
        foreach($links as $href=>$text){
            if($page!=$links){
            echo '<li><a href="?page='.$href.'">'.$text.'</a></li>';
            }else{echo $text;}
        }
    ?>
```

I tought was sufficient add an  for the title but doesn't work. I don't know what to do for keywords and descriptions. I don't use databases.

This is an example of page that will be included:
example.php:

```
  <p style="background:#ffa">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetaur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
  incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
  exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute 
  irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
  pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui 
  officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
```

Comment: try this

    `if($page!=$href){`

Comment: Please clarify your question and what you attempt to achieve, I understand that you want to include Meta Description and Meta Keywords dynamically on a per-page basis, is that right ? The problem is you don't have access to the meta in your "page.php"

Comment: RST:Nothing changes
@XhkUnlimit: that's right. Actually page.php doesn't exist. Menu creates ?page. .php is to tell that ?page loads a .php file. I don't know if I'm explaining good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the modification from @RST
And the described questions, here is a runnable that suits your needs.
You just have to add a page parameter and it seems to fit. Please check elsewhere if it still not works on your side(Php setting, etc).

[Runnable Code](http://runnable.com/VCSTOzrmi6gVxuJl/)

Comment: Doesn't work. $page is a variable, not a file. I added an example of page that will be loaded as "$page.php"

Comment: See modifications above ^^

Comment: Done
 http://runnable.com/VCSbKdI0-Ocuiy-w/output
http://runnable.com/VCSYsvEy0xov2fNi/my-for-php
without image

Comment: Oh almost forgot: I don't know why, but when I click (left-click) on a link of menu, is not opens. I must click (right-click) and select "Open in another page". I tried with Chrome, Firefox and Explorer but result is the same. Do you know why?

Comment: I don't think so. No browsers alerts me that he's blocking popup.